# Get dates between 2 dates in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How do you get list of dates inside of 2 dates?

Currently in my `booking` table I have 2 fields like `starts_at` and `ends_at`

If I use a query something like this

`SELECT starts_at, ends_at FROM booking`

This will give me all of records exists

[image]

But what I want is to list all of dates records uniquely

Let say in the first row of record `2020-08-19` to `2020-09-16`

This will be the output

```
    2020-08-19
    2020-08-20
    2020-08-21
    ......continuation
    2020-09-15
    2020-09-16
```

and on the second row there is `2020-06-04` to `2020-06-09`

This will be

```
 2020-06-04
 2020-06-05
 2020-06-06
 2020-06-07
 2020-06-08
 2020-06-09
```

as you can see all between dates are being dropdown.

and the final output of that should be the collected dates will be arranged based on the recent like this

```
 2020-06-04 (added dates from 2nd row)  
 2020-06-05
 2020-06-06
 2020-06-07
 2020-06-08
 2020-06-09

 2020-08-19 (added dates from 1st row)
 2020-08-20
 2020-08-21
 ......continuation
 2020-09-15
 2020-09-16
```

Just in case some dates are being duplicated it should be counted/read as one. since all days are being arranged.

Comment: this is what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725349/mysql-expand-date-range-into-new-rows

Comment: can we done this by not creating new table, just a query only?

Comment: Specify your MySQL version.

Comment: Is mysql necessary? Hmm maybe query that is appropriate to all version is a must. Btw here's my mysql "`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.37, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper` but in my local I'm using xampp/phpmyadmin

Comment: You will need some method to generate the numbers and dates.. I don't think you can without something like that.. you can always create a temporary table.. use it and throw it away after the query!

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL 8+

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT starts_at, ends_at, starts_at single_date 
         FROM booking
         UNION ALL
         SELECT starts_at, ends_at, single_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
         FROM cte
         WHERE single_date < ends_at )
SELECT DISTINCT single_date
FROM cte
ORDER BY 1;
```

For MySQL 5+ you must use generated numbers table with the numbers from `0` to at least `MAX(ends_at - starts_at)`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT booking.starts_at + INTERVAL n.n DAY single_date
FROM booking
-- assuming 99 days is enough
JOIN ( SELECT n1.n*10+n2.n n
       FROM (SELECT 0 n UNION SELECT 1 UNION ... UNION SELECT 9) n1
       JOIN (SELECT 0 n UNION SELECT 1 UNION ... UNION SELECT 9) n2 ) n
WHERE booking.starts_at + INTERVAL n.n DAY <= booking.ends_at;
```